# How to clear the cache in Solr?

Tags: caching, solr, lucene, information-retrieval

I'm trying to compare the performance of different Solr queries. In order to get a fair test, I want to clear the cache between queries.

How is this done? Of course, one can restart the server, I was curious if there is a quicker way.

Comment: To get an even fairer test (depending on what you are actually measuring), you could could also clear the OS buffer cache before every test (see http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches).

Comment: @jpountz thanks for the link. I tested it with `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` but it does not clear the Solr caches.

Comment: Right, it only clears the OS cache. To clear solr caches, I think having autowarmCount=0 and running a commit would work http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#autowarmCount '

Answer (score 7):

I'm using version 4.2.1 and even with `autowarmCount="0"` the cache is not updated after doing a Dataimport.

In that case, on Solr Admin (usually `http://localhost:8983/`)

Go to **Core Admin** and click **Reload**. 
When refreshed, you should see a green check mark on the "current" field.

Answer (score 3):

Disable all the caches from `solrconfig.xml`.

Note that the Lucene FieldCache will still be enabled.

Comment: The question is about clearing cache, not disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for thorough details

If you want to disable a cache (or all), comment out those sections in solrconfig.xml and restart solr.

example diable queryResultCache

```
   <!-- 
   <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                      size="5000"
                      initialSize="5000"
                      autowarmCount="2000"/>

-->
```